# whitespace is not allowed between stringprefix and bytesprefix?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am not able to understand this statement in python documentation.

> "whitespace is not allowed between the stringprefix or bytesprefix and the rest of the literal."

[Documentation link](https://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals)

Comment: `b 'abc'` and `u 'foo'` are invalid.

Comment: can u provide the valid example?

Comment: `u "bad"`, `u"good"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A string or bytes prefix is the `u` or `b` that precedes the literal to specify which one you want.  That sentence is saying that you cannot have whitespace in between the prefix and the literal itself.  In other words:

```
u "not allowed"
b   'still not allowed'
```

and

```
u'good'
b"also good"
```